# oracle 11gR2 full-width percentage sign in like clause

Tags: oracle

I found this in oracle's [official document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52144):

> Only ASCII-equivalent underscore (_) and percent (%) characters are
>   recognized as pattern-matching characters. Their full-width variants,
>   present in East Asian character sets and in Unicode, are treated as
>   normal characters.

But strangely, my full-width percentage sign ％ works just like half width %, below is my java code:

```
Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@******", "***", "***" );
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("select * from v$nls_parameters");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + ": " + rs.getString(2));
}
stmt.execute("select * from dual where '123' like '12％'");
rs = stmt.getResultSet();
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

The output is:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE: JAPANESE
NLS_TERRITORY: JAPAN
NLS_CURRENCY: ¥
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY: JAPAN
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS: .,
NLS_CALENDAR: GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT: RR-MM-DD
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE: JAPANESE
NLS_CHARACTERSET: AL32UTF8
NLS_SORT: BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT: HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT: RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT: HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT: RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY: \
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: UTF8
NLS_COMP: BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS: BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP: FALSE
X
```

But strangely, in sqlplus:

```
SQL> select * from dual where '123' like '12％';

no rows selected
```

And, the session's nls parameters are different now:

```
SQL> select * from v$nls_parameters;

PARAMETER                               VALUE
-------------------------------------   ----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                            AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY                           AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY                            $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY                        AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS                  .,
NLS_CALENDAR                            GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                         DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE                       AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET                        AL32UTF8
NLS_SORT                                BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                         HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT                    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT                      HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT                 DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY                       $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                  UTF8
NLS_COMP                                BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS                    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP                     FALSE

19 rows selected.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the '%' is being translated differently what would be the result if you do this query in both Java and SQLplus:
select dump('%') from dual;

Comment: Sorry, I just used the half-width variant... Java gives: Typ=96 Len=3: 239,188,133. Sqlplus gives: Typ=96 Len=9: 239,191,189,239,191,189,239,191,189

Comment: I don't think 1 character will ever be 9 long.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it's well and truly 9 long...

Comment: Looks like a repeating group of three bytes. 239,191,189. Not sure how you get that from a 1 character string.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to escape the special characters % _ (plus the escape character itself), like

select * from dual where '123' like '12\%' escape '\'